# JQuery animate .css() rather then using .anmiate()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to aniamte the change of the margin-top of a div.

Normally I would so this as such:

```
 $("#mydiv").animate({ marginTop: '+='+myvar}, 200);
```

But this always adds (or subtracts) the value. I want a way to simply aniamte the *change* in value.

For example: if the div starts of with a margin top of 100 and myvar value is 50 I want to animate the div so it shrinks back to 50. Likewise if the myvar value is 200 I want to animate the change so grows to 200.

I can achieve this somewhat but resetting the CSS, eg:

```
$("#mydiv").css("margin-top", "0px");
$("#mydiv").animate({ marginTop: '+='+myvar}, 200);
```

each time but that makes it a bit clunky.

Does anyone know of a may to achieve this?

(Ps: without using CSS transitions)

EDIT: Added my code below

```
$("#info1tab").click(function() {
  $(".textbox").slideUp('200');
  $("#info1").delay(300).slideDown('200');
  var itemheight = $("#info1").css("height");
  var itemheightint = parseInt(itemheight);
  $("#photobox").animate({ marginTop: itemheightint }, 200);

});

$("#info2tab").click(function() {
  $(".textbox").slideUp('200');
  $("#info2").delay(300).slideDown('200');
  var itemheight = $("#info2").css("height");
  var itemheightint = parseInt(itemheight);
  $("#photobox").animate({ marginTop: itemheightint }, 200);

});
```

Comment: go through this tutorial, and let me know if this help http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-1/

Comment: are you asking something like this ??
$('#left-bg).click(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({'width': '100%'},600);
    });

Comment: @X-Factor somewhat: I have 2 divs: Both are postion absolute. the one above has a varying dynamic height that changes on click. The margin of the lower div must change in response to the changes in heigh of the first

Comment: `But this always adds (or subtracts) the value.` This is wrong. You can always specify the final value. See [this example](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#entry-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is wrong with `$('#mydiv').animate({marginTop: myvar});`?

http://jsfiddle.net/muVsE/

Comment: that makes sense - but it just doesnt happen for me. Am adding my code to the top

Answer (score 0):

Create additional CSS classes that has the CSS properties you want and then do:

```
$("#mydiv").addClass("classname", 1000);
```

OR

```
$("#mydiv").removeClass("classname", 1000);
```

Comment: Available in jQuery UI only. Not in core jQuery

Comment: Is it a big deal to add jQuery UI?

Comment: Yes, its a big deal if he doesnt want it. He hasnt tagged 'jQuery UI' in his question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$("#mydiv").css("margin-top", "0px");
$("#mydiv").animate({ marginTop: topMargin+myvar}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CFNUJ/)

```
$('#left-bg, #right-bg').click(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({'width': '100%'},600).siblings().animate({'width':'0'},600);
    });
```

Or you can use this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CFNUJ/1/)

```
$('#left-bg, #right-bg').click(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({'width': '100%'},600).siblings().animate({'width':'0'},600);
        $('<button class="show">Show all</button>')
            .appendTo('#wrapper');
    });

    $('.show').live('click',
                    function(){
                        $('#left-bg').animate(
                            {
                                'width': '50%'
                            },600);
                        $('#right-bg').animate(
                            {
                                'width': '50%'
                            },600);
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
```

Or you can use this to expand one div and shrink other at the same time:

```
$('.cell')
    .on('mouseenter', function(){
        $(this).animate ({width:"75%"},"slow").siblings('.cell').animate({'width': '15%'}, "slow");
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).add($(this).siblings('.cell')).animate ({width:"45%"},"slow");
    });
```

Regards.